# Iterate through ViewModel list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am working on a web app using Asp.Net Core 2.2 MVC and Entity Framework, of which I'm fairly new to.

I am attempting a process whereby a user creates an incident and is presented with a question, if the answer is yes a page will load, but if the answer is no the next question will appear.

I am using a ViewModel to store my questions as a list. What is the best practice for returning the first question to I can iterate through each on a button click?

My view model is as follows:

```
public class PathwayViewModel
{
    public List<StageQuestion> StageQuestion{ get; set; }
    public Incident Incident { get; set; }
}
```

and my StageQuestion model class is as follows

```
public class StageQuestion
{
    // PK
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // FK to Incident Type
    public int IncidentTypeId { get; set; }
    // FK to Stage
    public int StageId { get; set; }
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }

    public virtual IncidentType IncidentType { get; set; }
    public virtual Stage Stage { get; set; }
}
```

My controller method is as follows:

```
public IActionResult Pathway (int? id)
{
    PathwayViewModel path = new PathwayViewModel();
    var incident = _context.Incident
        .Include(i => i.IncidentType)
        .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);
    path.Incident = incident;
    var stageQuestions = _context.StageQuestion.Where(x => x.IncidentTypeId == incident.IncidentTypeId)
        .Include(s => s.Stage)
        .Include(o => o.Stage.Outcome)
        .ToList();
    path.StageQuestion = stageQuestions;
    return View(path);
}
```

my HTML is as follows:

```
@model Path2019.ViewModels.PathwayViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Pathway";
 }

<h1>Pathway</h1>

<table class="table">
   <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>
            Stage text
        </th>
        <th>
            Question Text
        </th>
        <th>
            Type of Incident
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.StageQuestion)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.Stage.StageName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.QuestionText)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.IncidentType.Type)
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you mean by: "using First() just returns the first string character of each question." ? Where are you using First() and it returns first character ?

Comment: I receive errors when trying to use it in my controller method and in searching similar questions, the suggestion has been to use it in the view page e.g. <td>@item.Stage.StageName.First()</td>
which returns the first character from the question. I have edited the question to clarify.

Comment: item.Stage.StageName.First() returns the first character because item.Stage.StageName is a string and string is an array of chars so when you call First() on an array of chars you get the first character

Comment: Yes I know - I only mentioned I had tried this (and it doesn't work) because in looking for similar questions, this was the solution.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. As it stands, it's very unclear what you're asking. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question accordingly. You're far more likely to get a quick and definitive answer.

Comment: Thank you for the constructive criticism - I have edited my question so hope that helps a bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > What is the best practice for returning the first question to I can iterate through each on a button click?

Still unclear about your scenario .Base on your description , i assume you want to show the `StageQuestion` one by one when clicking the `Next` button . If you want to filter the data on server side , you can create action link :

```
@Html.ActionLink("Next", "Pathway", new { index = ViewBag.NextIndex })
```

And modify your view model to include a single question :

```
public class PathwayViewModel
{           
    public StageQuestion StageQuestion { get; set; }
}
```

Then fliter the record on server side :

```
public ActionResult Pathway(int? id,int? index)
{
    int currentIndex = index.GetValueOrDefault();
    if (currentIndex == 0)
    {
        ViewBag.NextIndex = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.NextIndex = index + 1;
    }

    ........

    PathwayViewModel path = new PathwayViewModel();
    var stageQuestion = _context.StageQuestion.Where(x => x.IncidentTypeId == incident.IncidentTypeId)
    .Include(s => s.Stage)
    .Include(o => o.Stage.Outcome).OrderBy(x=>x.Id).Skip(currentIndex).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();

    path.StageQuestion = stageQuestion;



    return View(path);
}
```

With above code you should also add below two logic:

1. Also create a viewbag and save current Incident id , also append id value to `@Html.ActionLink`
2. Add logic to confirm whether current index is the last record in database , you can get the max account of records and compare them .

If above code sample doesn't meet your requirement , please feel free to let me know .